How to provide opencl3.0 program scope global support for the new device
How do you define global variables outside the kernel,Or how do you support opencl3.0's __opencl_c_feature
#define SIZE 2
int global foo[SIZE] ;

int
baz (int i)
{
  return foo[i];
}

kernel void
bar (global int* input,
     global int* output,
     constant int* foo)
{
    const uint id = get_global_id (0);
    output[id] = input[id] + baz (id);
}


The normal way is to create a buffer, then have a pointer to it as a kernel argument.

Yes, usually.But program scope global variables are optional for devices supporting OpenCL 3.0.I'm working on getting this feature supported on my device.
